# [vaadin 6][Combobox] Dont show Suggestionbox when no Suggestion is in it

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin

Im using [Vaadin 6](https://vaadin.com/home) in our Project and i wanted to use the [Combobox](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler-for-vaadin6#ComboBoxNewItems) as an element for textinput and selection. This is working fine, but i wondered if there is a possibility to not show the suggestion window, if there aren't any suggestion.

(wanted to upload a picture but wasn't allowed to)

I studied the code of the combobox and searched in the web so far for solution, but i could'nt get any infos about this topic.

So does someone has an idea how this might work out?

regards

Comment: Can you post the code for a working example of the problem?

Comment: Hey, i think a Code is not really needed. Just create a new Combobox() and type something in that isn't in the container.

Answer (score 0):

If the `container` is empty add your own style to the `Combobox:`

```
comboBox.addStyleName( "empty-cb" );
```

Then add this to the CSS file:

```
.v-filterselect-suggestpopup-empty-cb {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, that could be a good input for my problem thank you. But the emty suggestion-box is also shown, when there actually are values in the container, but the user types something in that doesn't match. can i somehow proof that case?

Comment: [Here](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/7436) is a solution for `TextChangeEvents` and you can use `getFilteredOptions` method but that returns the previous filtered list. :( Besides the suggestpopup div is not refreshed.